# How to make dynamic column color in column chart usig google chart

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

i am using google chart and displaying column chart. That's working fine. my code is

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['columnchart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartTwo);
function drawChartTwo() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Type', 'Total'],
  <?php
      foreach($val as $data){
        echo "['".$data['type']."', ".$data['total']."],";
      }
  ?>                    
]);

var options = {
  hAxis: {
      title: 'Type'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Total'
    },
  'width':830,
  'height':300,
   'title': 'Outage Analysis',
   'is3D': true,
   //set color base on $data['unit']
};


    var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_bar'));

    chart1.draw(data, options);
}
```

now, in my database i have another column **$data['unit']** and it have four different category and i want to display different colors of column for different category. so, my question is how can i use my php column **$data['unit']** to set colors on column in column chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `'style'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)

you can populate the column with html color strings...

e.g. --> `#f44336`

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Type', 'Total', {role: 'style'}],
  <?php
      foreach($val as $data){
        echo "['".$data['type']."', ".$data['total'].", '".$data['color']."'],";
      }
  ?>
]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Type', 'Total', {role: 'style'}],
    ['A', 10, '#f44336'],
    ['B', 14, '#e91e63'],
    ['C', 16, '#9c27b0'],
    ['D', 22, '#673ab7'],
    ['E', 28, '#3f51b5'],
    ['F', 14, '#2196f3']
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 300,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: it help me a lot. it's working when i load packages as corechart...but i also want to display column in 3D...it's note working in corechart....any solution with diff. color and 3D chart simultaneously?

Comment: 3D? only google chart with 3D that i'm aware of is PieChart -- column roles work with the `'corechart'` package, but not _material_ packages, such as `'bar'` or `'line'`...